# MySQL encrypt database files

Tags: mysql

Please help me with the following task:
We need to store all data in MySQL (important) encrypted (mostly int, float, double) so no one could read the raw data in the MySQL in case of hacking.

Project is built on PHP + MySQL (Yii framework)

Please advice any solution, preferably free one :)

Thanks!

Comment: ...thereby eliminating any chance of indexing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hard work about indexes, because encrypted data cannot be indexed so searching that row will not be easy.

**I recommend Aes :**

AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() can be considered the most cryptographically secure encryption functions currently available in MySQL.

```
INSERT into user (first_name, address) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('Person', 'myword'),AES_ENCRYPT('Person', 'myword'));

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'myword'), AES_DECRYPT(address, 'myword') from user;
```

**Aes Encrypt Explanation:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

**Aes Decrypt Explanation:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt

---

**All Mysql Encryption and Compression Functions :**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

**This article is best about Mysql Database Security:**

http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips

Comment: if the key (like myword) has to be used so often in pages, will that be security concern itself ?

Comment: This is just basic example @WhirlMind. Actually there is no 'myword' in the real code. You can use hashed key like md5 or better one.